# Windows Cmake Error: No CUDA toolset found

Tags: opencv, image-processing, cmake, darknet

I was doing a project about image processing. I installed darknet, OpenCV and NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2. I was able to get build on OpenCV, but when trying to get build on darknet, it gives the following errors and I couldn't find the solution even though I searched for hours.

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:367 (message):
  No CUDA toolset found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:32 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeDetermineCUDACompiler.cmake:72 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:60 (enable_language)
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution to the `No CUDA toolset found` problem was to add the following to the CMake command:

```
-DCMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET="cuda=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2"
```

As well as copying the 4 VS integration files (from `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2\extras\visual_studio_integration\MSBuildExtensions`) to both:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations`
- and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations`

After all this CMake was happy with CUDA and started compiling. I didn't reinstall CUDA or anything.

Comment: Was building bitsandbytes for Win10 and only the first line (-DCMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET=...) was enough to pass through. Thanks a lot, Roy!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both the "development" and "Visual Studio Integration" components installed.
If you have only the first one installed (i.e. you have all you need to develop with cuda) but not the latter, then CMake won't find cuda!

just run the installer again and select "Visual Studio Integration" component (even without reinstalling the rest)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, by this step you probably have installed the cuda toolkit and visual studio but which one did you installed first?

I recommend installing visual studio 2017 community edition, then reinstall the CUDA toolkit, do not uninstall the current version that you have, this will create the Visual studio support for your cuda. Then at the time of "configure" in CMake, choose Visual Studio 2017 as compiler, I hope this help you.

edit: I used CMake 3.16.0

Answer (score 0):

It is effective to reinstall cuda without uninstalling the original cuda

Answer (score 0):

Cuda is only half-heartedly supported on Windows. Nvidia focuses on gamers on windows and developers on linux.

In my case the cuda toolkit package is found but enable_language returns the error.
To make it better, I have two projects that are almost identical, one works the other not.
In my case you need to switch the compiler kit from Visual Studio Build tools to Community Edition Build tools.

It's the same compiler, I never understood why Microsoft creates "two kits" using the same compiler.
Well, one works with cuda+cmake and one not.